# Best practice for abbreviated words in navigation links?

Tags: accessibility

For our site main nav, when a smartphone user enlarges font size, I'm considering switching the text of nav items to an abbreviated "short text" version, e.g., "Continuing Professional Education (CPE) Evaluations" would switch to appear as "CPE Evals". For accessibility, should I have a screen reader read the full text and ignore the short text - or just let the screen reader read the short text? In some cases, the abbreviated text will sound weird when read aloud, e.g., "Orntn" for "Orientation"

Comment: So, wow it looks like there's an abbr element ... and this seems to be a deeper subject. Stay tuned for findings ...

Answer (score 1):

So, the website powermapper tested the abbr element with a ton of screen readers and found issues with the abbr element. Likely I'll still use it but aria-hidden=true on it, and use a span with bootstrap's sr-only with the full text.